# Compiling VS Publishing a website in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-deployment, msdeploy

Is there any difference using aspnet_compiler with Web application folder and using Publish from Visual Studio and using 'File System' publish method as publishing method ?

Answer (score 1):

Compiling creates a new DLL of your website in your bin directory.

Publishing will compile your website, run all of the build job items, create an output directory (if required), copy all of the required files to the output directory, minimize your javascript code (when configured to do so), create a database, and [much more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28VS.100%29.aspx).